# POST request with JSON server only inserting the Id, no content

Tags: http-post, json-server

server and normally I got it to work. However this time there is an boundary I want to save some time.

I have the following json file:

```
{   "posts": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "React",
      "category": "React-Development",
      "imageUrl": "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_1280.jpg",
      "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime mollitia, molestiae quas vel sint commodi repudiandae consequuntur voluptatum laborum numquam blanditiis harum quisquam eius sed odit fugiat iusto fuga praesentium optio, eaque rerum! Provident similique accusantium nemo autem. Veritatis obcaecati tenetur iure eius earum ut molestias architecto voluptate aliquam nihil, eveniet aliquid culpa officia aut! Impedit sit sunt quaerat, odit,tenetur error, harum nesciunt ipsum debitis quas aliquid. Reprehenderit, quia. Quo neque error repudiandae fuga? Ipsa laudantium molestias eos sapiente officiis modi at sunt excepturi expedita sint? Sed quibusdam recusandae alias error harum maxime adipisci amet laborum. Perspiciatis minima nesciunt dolorem! Officiis iure rerum voluptates a cumque velit ",
      "date": "23/34/2021"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "React",
      "category": "React-Development",
      "imageUrl": "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_1280.jpg",
      "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime mollitia, molestiae quas vel sint commodi repudiandae consequuntur voluptatum laborum numquam blanditiis harum quisquam eius sed odit fugiat iusto fuga praesentium optio, eaque rerum! Provident similique accusantium nemo autem. Veritatis obcaecati tenetur iure eius earum ut molestias architecto voluptate aliquam nihil, eveniet aliquid culpa officia aut! Impedit sit sunt quaerat, odit,tenetur error, harum nesciunt ipsum debitis quas aliquid. Reprehenderit, quia. Quo neque error repudiandae fuga? Ipsa laudantium molestias eos sapiente officiis modi at sunt excepturi expedita sint? Sed quibusdam recusandae alias error harum maxime adipisci amet laborum. Perspiciatis minima nesciunt dolorem! Officiis iure rerum voluptates a cumque velit ",
      "date": "23/34/2021"
    },
    

  ],   "category": [
    "React-Development",
    "Vue3-Topics",
    "Angular",
    "Backend",
    "Vue-Development",
    "Angular-Development"   ] }
```

I tried to post with and without Id. Should also work without Id I suppose.

```
   {
            "id": 99,
            "title": "React",
            "category": "React-Development",
            "imageUrl": "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_1280.jpg",
            "text": "Hello World",
            "date": "23/34/2021"
        }
```

However the result I got after a couple of tries.

```
    {
        "id": 9   
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Found it! Most likely you didn't change to JSON in the dropdown menu to the right of Body's options row.

[image: Check the image]